# SFINAE enable_if explicit constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

I'm trying to switch between an explicit and an implicit conversion constructor via `enable_if`.

My code currently looks like

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

enum class enabled {};

template <bool B, typename T = void> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;
template <bool B, typename T = void> using disable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<!B, T>::type;

template <std::intmax_t A> struct SStruct
{
    static constexpr std::intmax_t a = A;
};

template <typename T> struct SCheckEnable : std::integral_constant<bool, T::a == 0>
{
};

template <typename U, typename T> class CClass
{
    public:
        template <typename T2, enable_if_t<SCheckEnable<U>::value, enabled>...> constexpr CClass(T2 v) : val(v) {};
        template <typename T2, disable_if_t<SCheckEnable<U>::value, enabled>...> explicit constexpr CClass(T2 v) : val(v) {};

    private:
        T val;
};

int main()
{
    CClass<SStruct<0>, double> a = 1;                             // should use implicit constructor
    CClass<SStruct<1>, double> b = CClass<SStruct<1>, double>(1); // should use explicit constructor
}
```

The `true` in the `enable_if`s is dependent of the template parameter `U`

If I try to compile this minimal example with `g++ 4.9.1` and `--std=c++11` enabled I get the following errors

```
sfinae.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<bool B, class T> using disable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<(! B), T>::type [with bool B = true; T = enabled]’:
sfinae.cpp:13:52:   required from here
sfinae.cpp:7:95: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, enabled>’
 template <bool B, typename T = void> using disable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<!B, T>::type;
                                                                                               ^
sfinae.cpp:19:68: error: prototype for ‘constexpr CClass<U, T>::CClass(T2)’ does not match any in class ‘CClass<U, T>’
 template <typename U, typename T> template <typename T2> constexpr CClass<U, T>::CClass(T2 v) : val(v)
                                                                    ^
sfinae.cpp:13:77: error: candidates are: template<class U, class T> template<class T2, int ...<anonymous> > constexpr CClass<U, T>::CClass(T2)
   template <typename T2, disable_if_t<true, enabled>...> explicit constexpr CClass(T2 v);
                                                                             ^
sfinae.cpp:12:67: error:                 template<class U, class T> template<class T2, enabled ...<anonymous> > constexpr CClass<U, T>::CClass(T2)
   template <typename T2, enable_if_t<true, enabled>...> constexpr CClass(T2 v);
                                                                   ^
```

Any idea how to select between explicit and implicit construction based on parameter `U` here?

Comment: I can get [this to work just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f37eef8d7c290602). Not sure what the differences are between your code and mine.

Comment: Could `constexpr` be the cause for this?

Comment: No. It shouldn't have any effect on SFINAE. Might have to do with defining it outside the class and the way you're doing that but I'm not entirely convinced.

Comment: If `true` here isn't the actual code but dependent on the on a template parameter, then your code should work.

Comment: @Rapptz Defining the ctor immediately removes all the errors except the first one (`no type named 'type'...`) in my minimal example up there.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I use something like `std::integral_constant<bool, U::a == 0>::value` as bool for the `enable_if`s, where `U::a` is an `static constexpr std::intmax_t a = ...;`

Comment: In order for SFINAE to happen, the construction needs to contain template parameters from the *immediate* template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
template <class...> struct null_v : std::integral_constant<int, 0> {};
```

and define the constructors as

```
template <typename T2,
          long = null_v<enable_if_t<SCheckEnable<U>::value, T2>>::value>
constexpr CClass(T2 v) : val(v) {};

template <typename T2,
          int = null_v<disable_if_t<SCheckEnable<U>::value, T2>>::value>
explicit constexpr CClass(T2 v) : val(v) {};
```

Making the argument dependent and actually instantiated. 
[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60aa171e1d2627ba).

[temp.deduct]/8:

> If **a substitution** results in an invalid type or expression, type
>   deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be
>   ill-formed if written **using the substituted arguments**.

In your case the error occurs outside of any substitution, so that's not causing a deduction failure but rather makes your code ill-formed.

Comment: Compiles and works as it should... Where exactly lies the difference between my try and your solution?

Comment: If I understood @0x499602D2 comment correctly, the enable_if needs to 'process' something with `T2`, as this is the template parameter for the specific function to enable or disable. Did I get that right? :)