# How to disambiguate this construction in a templated conversion operator?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, ambiguous

After being confused why my code gave me an ambiguity error on GCC but no errors on Clang, I simplified the code. It can be seen below.

```
struct Foo
{
    // Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
    // Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(int*) {}
};

struct Bar
{    
    template<typename T>
    operator T()
    {
        return Foo{nullptr};
    }
};

int main() { Foo f{Bar{}}; }
```

The errors are as follows.

```
main.cpp:17:18: error: call to constructor of 'Foo' is ambiguous
int main() { Foo f{Bar{}}; }
                 ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:1:8: note: candidate is the implicit move constructor
struct Foo
       ^
main.cpp:1:8: note: candidate is the implicit copy constructor
main.cpp:5:1: note: candidate constructor
Foo(int*) {}
^
```

I was unable to make it successfullycompile for Clang this time, so I suppose that was just a Clang bug and this is the intended behavior.

When I explicitly delete the copy and move constructors (i.e. uncomment the top two lines of code), I instead get

```
note: candidate constructor has been explicitly deleted
```

but still an error. How would I go about disambiguating the construction here, then?

Note that I specifically added the `Foo{nullptr}` instead of just `nullptr`, but there is no difference. Same with marking the `Foo` ctor explicit. This ambiguity error only occurs when `Bar`'s conversion operator is templated.

I can add some SFINAE to the conversion operator, but I am unsure of what I would exclude. For example, this would make it work:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, Foo>{}>* = nullptr>
```

This is another one that I found and this might be my answer:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, int*>{}>* = nullptr>
```

Comment: Why does the conversion operator need to be a template? Why not just `operator Foo()`?

Comment: @Justin, because it is an illustration (MCVE) which is not the actual problem?

Comment: Because `Foo` is not the only type I'll be casting it to. This templated conversion operator gives really nice semantics (see nlohmann/json).

Comment: @Evgeny that defeats the purpose of the implicit conversion :P

Comment: What would you actually like to be called in this example? Your Bar is convertable to both...

Comment: @SergeyA I'd like `Foo(int*)` to be called once and then the new `Foo` object be moved to `f`.

Comment: Goes to show unrestricted conversion is nearly always a mistake.

Comment: @DanielLangr That's a good guess. When I disable the conversion for references, though, i.e., `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<T>{}>`, I still get the same errors.

Comment: @PasserBy well, how would I go about making it implicit only in the right context?

Comment: Related: [SFINAE enable_if explicit constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949290/).

Comment: Might be interested in: [Implicit conversions and different behavior of compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51980680/580083).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To resolve the ambiguity, add `explicit` to the conversion operator declaration:

```
struct Bar
{    
    template<typename T>
    explicit operator T()
    {
        return Foo{nullptr}; 
    }
};
```

Why is it necessary? Because `Foo` has a constructor taking a `int*`, and so a `operator int*()` instantiation of `operator T()` *template* is being considered as part of overload resolution for the initialization of `f`. See under [[over.match.copy]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy):

> **1** [...] Assuming that **“`cv1 T`”** is the type of the object being initialized,
>   with `T` a class type, the candidate functions are selected as follows:
>
> - **(1.1)** The converting constructors of `T` are candidate functions.
> - **(1.2)** When the type of the initializer expression is a class type “`cv S`”,
>     **the non-explicit conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are
>     considered.** When initializing a temporary object ([class.mem]) to be
>     bound to the first parameter of a constructor where the parameter is
>     of type “reference to possibly cv-qualified `T`” and the constructor is
>     called with a single argument **in the context of direct-initialization
>     of an object of type “`cv2 T`”, explicit conversion functions are also
>     considered.**

From (1.2) it follows that only implicit conversion functions are considered for the initialization, hence the ambiguity -- as the compiler cannot decide between constructing `f` using a reference to `Foo` or, as already mentioned, using a `int*` (obtained by way of *copy-initializing*) from the return value of `operator int*`. **However,** when the *initializer expression* is a *temporary object*, we also consider *explicit* conversions -- but only if they match a constructor taking a reference to `Foo`, our *"possibly cv-qualified `T`"*, i.e. our *copy* and *move constructor*s. This entire behavior is being consistent with [[class.conv.fct¶2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv#fct-2):

> A conversion function may be explicit ([dcl.fct.spec]), in which case
>   it is only considered as a user-defined conversion for
>   direct-initialization ([dcl.init]). **Otherwise, user-defined
>   conversions are not restricted to use in assignments and
>   initializations.**

And so, saying the same thing here for the 3rd time: if it isn't marked as `explicit`, there's nothing stopping the compiler from trying to *copy-initialize* an `int*` to be used for construction.

Comment: This is nice, as it resolves the constructor problem, but it disables other useful implicit conversions, e.g.`void fn(Foo)` will not be callable with `fn(Bar{})`, it will insteam require `static_cast`. So if there were a way to differenciate between construction and function call, that would be awesome

Comment: Okay, I finally got it. For fundamental types I use the implicit conversion operator and for the rest I use the explicit one. It took me a while, because I mistook `std::is_abstract` for `std::is_fundamental`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess after some digging: I get the same error with the following code:

```
struct Foo { Foo(int*) {} };

struct Bar {    
   operator Foo(); // { return Foo{nullptr}; }
   /* explicit */ operator int*();
};

int main() { Foo f{Bar{}}; }
```

And, when I uncomment the commented code, then the problem disappears. It seems to me that, in OP's original templated version, when implicit conversion is required from `Bar` to `Foo`, GCC only "instantiates" conversion operator declarations and then resolves overload before instantiating of their bodies.

As for why `explicit` helps, it is because in the second case, there is one more conversion required (`Bar`→`int*` and then `int*`→`Foo`).