# Implicit conversions and different behavior of compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

Motivated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51972738/580083)<sup>1</sup>, I created the following code:

```
struct X {
   X(int) {}
};

struct Y {    
   operator X() { return X{1}; }
   operator int() { return 1; }
};

int main() {
   X x(Y{});
}
```

[Live demo with error messages](https://wandbox.org/permlink/URvUeCMqrW33EzNU).

This code:

- throws an ambiguity error with all GCC and Clang versions (I have tried) if C++11/14 is enabled,
- throws an ambiguity error with some GCC and Clang versions if C++17 is enabled (e.g., GCC 8.2, GCC 6.3, Clang 5),
- compiles with some GCC and Clang version if C++17 is enabled (e.g., GCC 7.3, Clang 6).

The ambiguity stems from possible conversions:

1. `Y`→`X`,
2. `Y`→`int` and `int`→`X`,

since the compiler does not know which constructor of `X` it should use (copy/move or converting from `int`).

I wonder why there is such discrepancy in compilers behavior and whether the Standard says that this code should trigger an error or not.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that this is not a duplicate. In the linked question, OP asked about how to remove ambiguity. I ask why the behavior is different with different compilers.

Comment: I think this is another spin of [CWG Issue 2327](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2327).

Comment: Could also be [CWG Issue 2137](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2137)

Comment: @PatrickArtner I am not a native English speaker, so the wording might have been poorly chosen. However, I think the question is pretty clear, simply skip the "I wonder" part and begin with "why".

Comment: It was a defect in the language addressed in [P2828](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2828r0.html). Now both GCC and Clang accept your example without an error: https://godbolt.org/z/8T3xe11nr

Comment: MSVC bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/User-defined-conversion-to-class-type-di/10536580